# Magento 2 - can't change the zip code in order

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, orders, sales-order, zipcode

I have a very strange issue in Magento 2 orders. In some orders the first number in the zip code is removed automatically. For example 07716 will be 7716. So the zero was dropped.

I try to edit the zip code in the orders but is not work.

[image]

How I can fix this?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is Magento's bug, for work around update some other value also when updating postal code like street field, I think it will work fine. Then revert the change of other field which you updated with postal code i.e street field.

This is still in progress to merge by Magento, issue is resolved in this branch

https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/20103